# How to declare a variable of type Interface say List and assigning value directly?

Tags: java, selenium, interface

I have been thinking over this piece of code in selenium webdriver.Now,I do understand that Interfaces cannot be instantiated and that to do that we should do it via a class that implements the same.

Code is as below:

```
List<WebElement> divElements ;
divElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
```

Is it possible to assign values like shown above(why?) or should it not be:

```
List<WebElement> divElements=new ArrayList<>(); ;
divElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
```

How is it that code 1 is working?If anyone could clarify.

Comment: What do you think happens with the created ArrayList (in code example 2) when you call `divElements = ...` afterwards?

Comment: I thought we were initialising the array list when I use divElements =driver.findElements(By.tagName("div"));

Comment: That is right. And this is the reason why you do not need to call `new ArrayList<>()`. The object that will be created there, will be "lost" and garbage collected after the new assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference in effect between your two snippets.

Think of  any variable (other than one of a primitive type) as being a label for an object, rather like a little post-it note.  You create the label, you stick it on an object, and you can move it to another object if you like.  You can even set a variable to `null`, which means it's not stuck to an object at all.

The code `new ArrayList<>()` creates a new object.  Your code in the second snippet puts a label (variable) on that object, but immediately moves the label to an entirely different object.  This makes the original `ArrayList` completely irrelevant.  After either one of your snippets, the variable `divElements` will be stuck to the object that was returned by the `findElements` method.

Comment: Thanks to all for the reply.All the answers were helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of driver.findElements() is a single object: a List of WebElements. 
That can be assigned to the variable divElements and thats it.

You don't have to allocate an empty ArrayList for the result. That is void an will be lost and garbage collected after:

```
divElemens = driver.findElements(..)
```

Answer (score 1):

All variables of type `List<WebElement>` (and *any* class type in java) are *references*.  When you say

```
divElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
```

it sets `divElements` to whatever reference is returned by `findElements`.  It may be that `findElements` has instantiated a new object, which is a `List` (it could be any class that implements `List`); or maybe `findElements` is returning a reference to some object that was created previously; or maybe it returns `null`.  It doesn't much matter.  Whatever object `divElements` was referencing before, if any, doesn't matter either.  The reference gets replaced by a new reference.

The thing is here, unless `findElements` returns `null`, an object that implements a `List` *does* or *did* get instantiated, somewhere.  Doing this first:

```
List<WebElement> divElements = new ArrayList<>();
```

simply means that you set `divElements` to a reference to a new object that's just going to get thrown out.  It has no beneficial effect.